# What is the correct usage of sampler lod_options (MSL) in Metal shader?

Tags: ios, metal, metalkit

I'm trying to learn MSL through the [Metal Shading Language Specification](https://developer.apple.com/metal/Metal-Shading-Language-Specification.pdf), and saw that you can set LOD options when sampling a texture by specifying the options in the `sample` function. This is one of the examples given in the spec:

```
Tv sample(sampler s, float2 coord, lod_options options, int2 offset = int2(0)) const
```

`lod_options` include bias, level, gradient2d, etc.

I've looked all over but cannot find the usage syntax for this. Are these named arguments? Is `lod_options` a struct? For example, if I want to specify the LOD level, what is the correct way to do it? I know these options can also be specified in the sampler object itself, but if I want to do it here, what would be the right syntax to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `lod_options` type as such; you can think of it as a placeholder for one of the `bias`, `level`, `gradient2d`, etc. types. Each of these types is a different struct, which allows the Metal standard library to have an overloaded variant of the `sample` function for each such option.

To specify, for example, the mipmap level to sample, you'd provide a parameter of `level` type:

```
float4 color = myTexture.sample(mySampler, coords, level(1));
```